# Specific form of differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose the function

$$
f(x)=p(x)\,\mathrm{e}^{q(x)},
$$

is the solution to a differential equation.

From which family of differential equations would $ f $ arise?

Comment: is this really a differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example:
$$
\left(\frac{y}{p(x)}\right)'=\frac{y}{p(x)}q'(x)
$$
or equivalently
$$
p(x)y'-p'(x)y=p(x)q'(x)y,
$$
or
$$
y'-\left(\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}-q'(x)\right)y=0.
$$

Comment: Does this type of differential equation have a name?

Comment: It is a first order linear homogeneous ODE.